# Counting if 4 or more visits happen within 45 days of each other

Tags: sql, loops, sas

Here is sample data. i need to only keep a patient if they had 4 or more visits within 45 days of each other. I have transposed the dataset and used arrays to figure out one way of doing it, but am hoping for a more efficient way.

```
Pat_ID  Date        Prov_ID
    A       05/12/2012  X1
    A       05/12/2012  X2
    B       11/12/2012  X1
    B       11/20/2012  X1
    B       01/12/2013  X1
    B       03/22/2013  X1
    C       04/25/2013  X1
    C       04/25/2013  X2
    C       04/27/2013  X1
    C       05/12/2013  X1
    C       05/22/2013  X2
    C       04/25/2012  X3
    ...
```

I started by removing observations with less than 4 events.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

End Result should be a dataset with only the PAT_ID with 4 or more visits within 45 days.

Comment: Do 2 rows with the exact same date count as 2 visits or 1 visit?

Comment: What type of solution would you prefer, SAS or SQL?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a SAS (rather than SQL) based solution, using the `lag` function.  It only reads through the data one time, so should be pretty efficient, especially compared to the self-joiny style solutions.

First sort your data by ID and Visit Date (if it's not already)

```
proc sort data=YourData; 
    by Pat_ID Date;
run;
```

If you keep track of the Pat_ID and Date from 3 records back, you can test that it is within 45 days and that its the same patient.  If so - add it to the list.

```
data list_of_membs(keep=PAT_ID);
    set YourData;
    retain last_Pat_ID;*The last PAT_ID that was added to the list;

    pat_id_3back = lag3(Pat_ID); *PAT_ID from 3 records back;
    date_3back = lag3(date);

    If  pat_id = pat_id_3back 
        AND (date - date_3back) < 45 
        AND (PAT_ID != last_Pat_ID) THEN DO;
            output;
            last_PAT_ID = PAT_ID;
    END;
run;
```

Comment: This answer perfectly answers the original question, which patients had visits within 45 days of each other? But this answer does not address the related questions: Which patient visits were within 45 days of each other? How many were there? When did these visit-clusters occur? These seem to be natural questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to accomplish this by self joining the results and counting how many times a date occurs for the same patient within 45 days of the date on said row.

The below code is untested, but hopefully should get you headed in the right direction.

```
WITH X AS (
--your original query here
)

SELECT
X.*,
COUNT(Y.Date) over (PARTITION BY X.Pat_ID, X.VisitID) as [# of visits within 45 days after this one]
INTO #Y
FROM X
INNER JOIN X as Y on X.Pat_ID = Y.Pat_ID and Y.Date > X.Date and Y.Date < DATEADD(d,45,X.Date)

SELECT DISTINCT
*
FROM #Y
WHERE [# of visits within 45 days after this one] >= 3

DROP TABLE #Y
```

Comment: FYI - Error in SQL Server 2012: `Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 60
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

Comment: @BrennanPope SAS has implemented most of the guidelines set by ANSI, but not all. It also allows Data Step options, which might explain why you think this code would generate an error.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not this error might or should have occurred, it definitely did occur. This error message was copied from the messages tab in SSMS connected to a server running SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Good catch, I'll update my answer to use a temp table instead.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: When I first answered this question, I assumed that the results should be the records from the original table that were within 45 days of each other. I have now included a SQL Server implementation of Tim Sand's answer (one without a self-join) in case someone needs a SQL Server version in the future. I think that it's worth stating that if any data is required from the table other than just the pat_id, then it will require joining back to the table to get it.

```
DECLARE @PatientVisits TABLE
(
    VisitID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
    ,Pat_ID  VARCHAR(5)
    ,Date   DATETIME2
    ,Prov_ID VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @PatientVisits
VALUES

    ('A'       ,'05/12/2012'  ,'X1')
   ,('A'       ,'05/12/2012'  ,'X2')
   ,('B'       ,'11/12/2012'  ,'X1')
   ,('B'       ,'11/20/2012'  ,'X1')
   ,('B'       ,'01/12/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('B'       ,'03/22/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'04/25/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'04/25/2013'  ,'X2')
   ,('C'       ,'04/27/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'05/12/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'05/22/2013'  ,'X2')
   ,('C'       ,'04/25/2012'  ,'X3');

SELECT DISTINCT
    Pat_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Pat_ID
        ,Date AS CurrentDate
        ,LAG (Date,3,'00:00') OVER ( PARTITION BY Pat_ID ORDER BY Date ASC ) AS DateThreeVisitsAgo
    FROM @PatientVisits
) Visits
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,DateThreeVisitsAgo,CurrentDate) <= 45
```

Here is my original answer:

```
DECLARE @PatientVisits TABLE
(
    VisitID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
    ,Pat_ID  VARCHAR(5)
    ,Date   DATETIME2
    ,Prov_ID VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @PatientVisits
VALUES

    ('A'       ,'05/12/2012'  ,'X1')
   ,('A'       ,'05/12/2012'  ,'X2')
   ,('B'       ,'11/12/2012'  ,'X1')
   ,('B'       ,'11/20/2012'  ,'X1')
   ,('B'       ,'01/12/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('B'       ,'03/22/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'04/25/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'04/25/2013'  ,'X2')
   ,('C'       ,'04/27/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'05/12/2013'  ,'X1')
   ,('C'       ,'05/22/2013'  ,'X2')
   ,('C'       ,'04/25/2012'  ,'X3');

SELECT 
    VisitID
    ,Pat_ID
    ,Date
    ,Prov_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        P.VisitID
        ,P.Pat_ID
        ,P.Date
        ,P.Prov_ID
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY P.VisitID) AS NearVisitCount
    FROM @PatientVisits P
    JOIN @PatientVisits P2
        ON P.Pat_ID = P2.Pat_ID
        AND P.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-45,P2.Date) AND DATEADD(DAY,45,P2.Date)

) Visits
WHERE
    NearVisitCount >= 4 
GROUP BY 
    VisitID
    ,Pat_ID
    ,Date
    ,Prov_ID
```

Results:

```
VisitID Pat_ID  Date        Prov_ID
7       C       2013-04-25  X1
8       C       2013-04-25  X2
9       C       2013-04-27  X1
10      C       2013-05-12  X1
11      C       2013-05-22  X2
```

Comment: I would be happy to provide an example not using an identity as the primary key if that's what you really want.

Comment: I guess I assumed that more than just a list of patient ID's would be desired in the output. Looking back at the question, it seems that only a list of patient Id's was required. I will provide a SQL implementation of Tim Sand's answer for the sake of posterity.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work also:

```
    proc sql;
     create table want as 
     select a.Pat_ID, a.Date, a.Prov_ID from YourData as a
     left join  YourData as b
     on
      (
       a.pat_id = b.pat_id
       and  intck('day',b.date,a.date)>=45
      )
     join 
     (select pat_id, count(*) from YourData
      group by pat_id
      having count(*)>4
     ) as c
     on
     (
       a.pat_id = c.pat_id
     )
     where b.date is not missing;
   quit;
```